# Write a psql query to find users in a time interval

Tags: postgresql

I have user and team table.

- User table has `month, day, id, timezone and team_id`
- team table has `time (24 hour format) and id`

I have to find all users for which time in their local timezone is equal to time specified time for their team. My `cron runs every 15 minute` so i want to make sure no user got missed. How to write postgres query for this. I have written below query but i want to extend it so it take all the cases mentioned above

Cron runs in Nodejs

```
SELECT id, timezone
FROM user_table
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE user_table.timezone) = 9
  AND day = EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE user_table.timezone)
  AND month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE user_table.timezone);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your table structure and dependencies right, so this should work.

First create a table to track of users who have received wishes:

```
CREATE TABLE wished_users (
  user_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  wish_sent_at TIMESTAMPTZ
);
```

Then use the query to select eligible users and insert them into the wished_users table while considering the time range:

```
WITH eligible_users AS (
  SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.username,
    u.birthdate,
    u.timezone
  FROM user_table u
  JOIN team_table t ON u.team_id = t.id
  WHERE
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM u.birthdate AT TIME ZONE u.timezone) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE u.timezone)
    AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM u.birthdate AT TIME ZONE u.timezone) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE u.timezone)
    AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE u.timezone) = 8
    AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE u.timezone) >= 45
    AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW() AT TIME ZONE u.timezone) = 9
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM wished_users wu WHERE wu.user_id = u.user_id
    )
)
INSERT INTO wished_users (user_id, wish_sent_at)
SELECT user_id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM eligible_users;
```

Comment: Thanks Asi, one question here it taken forward fifteen minute like 9 to 9:15, i want 8:45 to 9. Also i was thinking it could be possible in case server crash this cron will miss the user, to solve that if we take the the time in consideration lets say from 12 am to time till now leaving 15 min window and i will keep an extra table to track which users already received a wish and ignore in next cron

Comment: Sure @sahil, please look at my edited comment.